# dplyr conditional mean of subset of group

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, group

My R dataframe looks like

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date1 = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-08-01"), to = as.Date("2022-09-12"), by = 7), 2), 
  Date2 = as.Date(c(rep("2022-08-15", times = 7), rep("2022-08-29", times = 7))), 
  Value = 1:14)
```

| Date1 | Date2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-15 | 1 |
| 2022-08-08 | 2022-08-15 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |
| 2022-08-15 | 2022-08-29 | 10 |
| 2022-08-22 | 2022-08-29 | 11 |
| ... |  |  |

Using a `magrittr` + `dplyr` chain, I want to add a new column that groups the data by `Date2` (and any other grouping columns) and shows the mean `Value` for that group when `Date1` is less than `Date2` and greater than "`Date2` - 2 weeks."

| Date1 | Date2 | Value | CondGrpMean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-15 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 2022-08-08 | 2022-08-15 | 2 | 1.5 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 2022-08-15 | 2022-08-29 | 10 | 10.5 |
| 2022-08-22 | 2022-08-29 | 11 | 10.5 |
| ... |  |  |  |

I'm looking at `dplyr::across()`, `dplyr::group_modify()`, but can't figure this out in anything like easy syntax that does not require a join.

I'm open to other straightforward solutions, but my current ideal answer would look something like

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(CondGrpMean = mean(Value %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Date1 < Date2 & 
      Date1 > Date2 - 14)))
```

The output values for `CondGrpMean` should be 1.5 for rows 1 - 7 and 10.5 for rows 8 - 14.

Comment: Just a comment to try to correct a few misconceptions. (A) Grouping: row 1 and row 2 both have different `Date1` values. You seem to want them in the same group--this means you **do not want to `group_by(Date1)`**. If you group by `Date1`, then only rows with the same `Date1` value can be in the same group.

Comment: Thank you, grouping by `Date2` is what that should have said (not `Date1`).

Comment: (B) `across` is used when you want to do the same thing on multiple columns. Like if you want to `log` all your numeric columns, or convert all columns to that have "day" in the column name to `Date` class. You're not doing similar things to multiple columns, so you don't want `across()`.

Comment: (C) `group_modify` is for when your function is so complex that it takes in a whole (sub) data frame and returns a whole (sub) data frame. When working on a column or two just can't get the job done. Like fitting a statistical model to each group, and and adding fitted values as a new column. You're not doing something that requires a whole data frame as input, so you don't want `group_modify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** There is no `filter` method for numeric vectors. Subscript `Value` as shown instead:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date2) %>%
  mutate(CondGrpMean = mean(Value[Date1 >= Date2-14 & Date1 < Date2])) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   Date1      Date2      Value CondGrpMean
   <date>     <date>     <int>       <dbl>
 1 2022-08-01 2022-08-15     1         1.5
 2 2022-08-08 2022-08-15     2         1.5
 3 2022-08-15 2022-08-15     3         1.5
 4 2022-08-22 2022-08-15     4         1.5
 5 2022-08-29 2022-08-15     5         1.5
 6 2022-09-05 2022-08-15     6         1.5
 7 2022-09-12 2022-08-15     7         1.5
 8 2022-08-01 2022-08-29     8        10.5
 9 2022-08-08 2022-08-29     9        10.5
10 2022-08-15 2022-08-29    10        10.5
11 2022-08-22 2022-08-29    11        10.5
12 2022-08-29 2022-08-29    12        10.5
13 2022-09-05 2022-08-29    13        10.5
14 2022-09-12 2022-08-29    14        10.5
```

**1a)** A variation of this is:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date2) %>%
  mutate(CondGrpMean = mean(Value[c(Date2 - Date1) %in% 1:14])) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2)** With base R:

```
Mean <- function(ix) with(df[ix, ], mean(Value[Date1 >= Date2-14 & Date1 < Date2]))
transform(df, CondGrpMean = ave(1:nrow(df), Date2, FUN = Mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this. You can deal with your conditions using `ifelse` and only include the `Value` you want by assigning others `NA`. Then use `na.rm` in your `mean` to get the correct values:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  Date1 = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-08-01"), to = as.Date("2022-09-12"), by = 7), 2), 
  Date2 = as.Date(c(rep("2022-08-15", times = 7), rep("2022-08-29", times = 7))), 
  Value = 1:14)

df %>%
  group_by(Date2) %>%
  mutate(CondGrpMean = mean(ifelse(Date1 < Date2 & Date1 >= Date2 - 14, 
                                   Value, 
                                   NA), na.rm = T
                            )
         )
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   Date2 [2]
#>    Date1      Date2      Value CondGrpMean
#>    <date>     <date>     <int>       <dbl>
#>  1 2022-08-01 2022-08-15     1         1.5
#>  2 2022-08-08 2022-08-15     2         1.5
#>  3 2022-08-15 2022-08-15     3         1.5
#>  4 2022-08-22 2022-08-15     4         1.5
#>  5 2022-08-29 2022-08-15     5         1.5
#>  6 2022-09-05 2022-08-15     6         1.5
#>  7 2022-09-12 2022-08-15     7         1.5
#>  8 2022-08-01 2022-08-29     8        10.5
#>  9 2022-08-08 2022-08-29     9        10.5
#> 10 2022-08-15 2022-08-29    10        10.5
#> 11 2022-08-22 2022-08-29    11        10.5
#> 12 2022-08-29 2022-08-29    12        10.5
#> 13 2022-09-05 2022-08-29    13        10.5
#> 14 2022-09-12 2022-08-29    14        10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your condition as a column and use it to subset the `Value` column that you take the `mean` of:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(Date2) %>%
  mutate(
    cond =  Date1 < Date2 & Date1 >= (Date2 - weeks(2)),
    CondGrpMean = mean(Value[cond])
)
# # A tibble: 14 × 5
# # Groups:   Date2 [2]
#    Date1      Date2      Value cond  CondGrpMean
#    <date>     <date>     <int> <lgl>       <dbl>
#  1 2022-08-01 2022-08-15     1 TRUE          1.5
#  2 2022-08-08 2022-08-15     2 TRUE          1.5
#  3 2022-08-15 2022-08-15     3 FALSE         1.5
#  4 2022-08-22 2022-08-15     4 FALSE         1.5
#  5 2022-08-29 2022-08-15     5 FALSE         1.5
#  6 2022-09-05 2022-08-15     6 FALSE         1.5
#  7 2022-09-12 2022-08-15     7 FALSE         1.5
#  8 2022-08-01 2022-08-29     8 FALSE        10.5
#  9 2022-08-08 2022-08-29     9 FALSE        10.5
# 10 2022-08-15 2022-08-29    10 TRUE         10.5
# 11 2022-08-22 2022-08-29    11 TRUE         10.5
# 12 2022-08-29 2022-08-29    12 FALSE        10.5
# 13 2022-09-05 2022-08-29    13 FALSE        10.5
# 14 2022-09-12 2022-08-29    14 FALSE        10.5
```